# Oracle PKG executing in other schema - not in schema specified in connection string in ODP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, odp.net

**Problem :** Oracle PKG executing in other schema - not in schema specified in connection string in ODP.net

**Environment**

We have 300+ schemas on a single database where ,

1. We are using Unmanaged ODP.net which is installed with oracle client installation.
2. No external Oracle.DataAccess.dll included in application. Fetching from GAC only.
3. A master schema have all the grants to access the child schemas objects.
4. Some public synonyms are there to access some tables from master schema from other schemas.
5. There is no synonyms for PKG PROC FUNC in any schemas.
6. Every schema have same list of PKG PROC FUNC
7. We are fetching data from procedures using below mentioned method.
8. This process and methods are running for last 3 year.

Suddenly when connecting to master schema and fetching data using PKG residing on master schema ,it is automatically connects to other schema and trying to execute same named procedures .

In .net debug session we can verify that we are passing below mentioned connection string which is perfectly Ok.

But whey the procedure execution is happening in different schema? where to look and how to look?

**Connection String**

Data Source=;User Id=;Password=;Min Pool Size=10;Connection Lifetime=120;Connection Timeout=120;Incr Pool Size=5; Decr Pool Size=2;Max Pool Size=150; Validate Connection = true

**Method for execution**

```
     public DataSet ExecuteQueryProcedure(string _ProcName, string[] _arrINPUTParamNames, string[] _arrINPUTParamValues, 
string constr, ref string strMsg)
            {
    strMsg = "";
    try
    {
    if (_arrINPUTParamValues.Length < _arrINPUTParamNames.Length)
    {
    Array.Resize(ref _arrINPUTParamValues, _arrINPUTParamNames.Length);
    for (int _intParamCount = 0; _intParamCount < _arrINPUTParamValues.Length; _intParamCount++)
    {
    _arrINPUTParamValues[_intParamCount] = _arrINPUTParamValues[_intParamCount] == null ? "" : _arrINPUTParamValues[_intParamCount];
    }
    }

    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr);
    con.Open();

    // create the command object and set attributes
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(_ProcName, con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.FetchSize = cmd.FetchSize * 8;

    OracleCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);

    int _intInputParamCount = 0;
    for (int _intParamCount = 0; _intParamCount < cmd.Parameters.Count; _intParamCount++)
    {
    if (cmd.Parameters[_intParamCount].Direction == ParameterDirection.Input)
    {
    _intInputParamCount++;
    cmd.Parameters[_intParamCount].Value = "";
    }
    }
    if (_intInputParamCount != _arrINPUTParamNames.Length)
    {
    strMsg = "Input Parameter count mismatch";
    return null;
    }

    for (int _intParamCount = 0; _intParamCount < cmd.Parameters.Count; _intParamCount++)
    {
    for (int _intSetParamCount = 0; _intSetParamCount < _arrINPUTParamNames.Length; _intSetParamCount++)
    {
    if (_arrINPUTParamNames[_intSetParamCount].ToUpper() == cmd.Parameters[_intParamCount].ParameterName.ToUpper())
    {
    cmd.Parameters[_intParamCount].Value = _arrINPUTParamValues[_intSetParamCount];
    break;
    }
    }
    }

    // create a data adapter to use with the data set
    OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
    // create the data set
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    // fill the data set

    DateTime dtBeforeTime = DateTime.Now;

    da.Fill(ds);

    DateTime dtAfterTime = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan ts = dtAfterTime - dtBeforeTime;


    // clean up our objects release resources
    ds.Dispose();
    da.Dispose();

    cmd.Dispose();
    con.Close();
    con.Dispose();

    return ds;
    }
    catch (OracleException Ex)
    {
    strMsg = Ex.Source + ": " + Ex.Message;
    return null;
    }
            }
```

Comment: MY suspicion is that the procedure you are calling was compiled with **authid current_user** rather than the default **authid definer**.

Comment: Thanks for feedback @brian , can you tell me how to check that.

Comment: select * from dba_procedures. 
The AUTHID column shows 'DEFINER' or 'CURRENT_USER'